# Jackson JSON translation

Tags: java, json, groovy, jackson

I am integrating with 3rd party WS that sends dates in different standards.
e.g. message body:

```
{
  "date" : "2016-09-12T16:00:00+0000"
}
```

By using following configuration jackson is able to deserialize it nicely into POJO:

```
public class Pojo {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    ZonedDateTime date;

    public ZonedDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(ZonedDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I wish to deserialize `date` from one pattern and then serialize it into one that is used by our system. I understand that I can break down mapping and deserialization in my code but maybe there is a cleaner way ?

Comment: I'm surprised that it can even compile as it should be `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` with double quotes

Comment: @NicolasFilotto it is in GROOVY

Comment: I guess you should mention it somewhere then

Answer (score 1):

You can specifically use `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonSerialize` and provide custom serializer/deserializer which extends [`StdSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html)/[`StdDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html). `serialize` and `deserialize` method for each has to be overridden. As an example:

```
// Field
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer)
ZonedDateTime date
```

And the `CustomDateSerializer`:

```
class CustomDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    public CustomDateSerializer(Class<ZonedDateTime> t) {
        super(t) 
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value))
    }
}
```

Similarly, for `deserialization`:

```
class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
 
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
 
    public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc) 
    }
 
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String date = jsonparser.getText()
        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(formatter, date)
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```